# how iOS generate DH public key(X.509 DER) by openssl to java server

Tags: ios, openssl, diffie-hellman

I generate DH public key(X.509 DER) by openssl to java server. But server parsing error. What's wrong？
iOS generate DH public key(X.509 DER) codes:

```
DH *dh2 = DH_new();
DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh1,512,DH_GENERATOR_2,NULL);
DH_generate_key(dh2);
unsigned char *resutChar = NULL;
int len = i2d_DHparams(dh, &resutChar);
NSData *puKeyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:resutChar length:length11];
NSString *puKeyBase64Str = [puKeyData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

the puKeyBase64Str send to java server.

java server parsing codes：

```
X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec=new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
KeyFactory keyFactory=KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
PublicKey pubKey=keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec=((DHPublicKey)pubKey).getParams();
```